# How to parse an array after stringify in json request

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json

I have an array, which I send with ajax to my controller for make some actions on it. It looks like this:

**jQuery**:

```
var url = window.location.pathname.split('/');

segments = [];
segments.push( url[3], url[4], url[5] );

$.ajax({
   'data': { array : JSON.stringify(segments) },
});
```

And then, when I get it in my controller, I have an ***array* *with 1 element***: key - "segments" and value with all values of an array segments.

What can be done for parse the array with 1 element into a new array with a few elements.

Thanks for attention and help

Comment: Can you re-word your question? Do you want to do something like `segments = {part3: url[3], part4:url[4], part5:url[5]};` ?

Comment: Evilzebra, if I do something like you suggest, then I will have an object instead of an array. So then how can I  convert it into array?

Comment: What server do you use? PHP? ASP.Net?

Comment: Andreas Furster, it specified in tags - php

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 2):

As per my understanding the solution as follows:

**Html file sample.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Smaple</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            var url = window.location.pathname.split('/');

            segments = [];
            segments.push( url[3], url[4], url[5] );
            console.log(segments);
            console.log(JSON.stringify(segments));
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "sample.php",
                'data': { 'segments' : JSON.stringify(segments) },
                success: function() {

            }});

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>TODO write content</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**And PHP file sample.php**

```
<?php
$segments = json_decode($_POST['segments']);
print_r($segments);
exit;
?>
```